# Android ripple cannot get desired color

Tags: java, android, xml, ripple, rippledrawable

The ripple xml is

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:color="@color/baseWhite">
    <item android:drawable="@color/baseRed" />
</ripple>
```

Name of the file is rounded_button_leave_submit.xml(v-21)

The button xml is

```
<Button
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edittext_button_height"
    android:id="@+id/submitLeave"
    android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_text_size"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_leave_submit"/>
```

As you can see the default base color for the ripple is red.And the ripple color is white.However the white is not "clear" white.It is somewhat a composite color of white and red combined.

Here baseWhite and baseRed are just hex color codes of white(#ffffff) and red(#d41217).What to do to get clear white?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @android:color/white

Comment: @Wizard No still composite red and white color coming

Comment: So you want a solid white rather than an opaque white?